# Share folders between PC and Android

Tags: android

I want to know how to share any folders between android and ubuntu. I've got it with WindowsXP. On my Android phone I've installed the app ES File Explorer. I've created a folder in the PC and it is shared. With the app from cellphone I can find the shared folder but when I try open it, the app says 'The account has no permissions' I don't know how to give these permissions.

Comment: How about just using DropBox or Ubuntu One (and Ubuntu One Files for Android) as an easier solution?

Comment: How are you connecting to the shared folder, is it via LAN or FTP (ES File Explorer has both these options to connect)

Answer (score 2):

Ohk.. I was trying the same thing, below is what worked:

In nautilus, right click on the folder you want to share and select 'sharing options', where you enable sharing the folder. In the same window, there are 2 other options: 'Allow others to create and delete files in this folder' and 'Guest Access'.
Check both the options.. Exit Nautilus (on computer) and ES file explorer (on android phone). Reopen ES file explorer and connect to the shared folder again...
That should fix the issue...

Answer (score 1):

Dowload and install the android app [`Airdroid`](http://www.airdroid.com/) from Playstore..
It will share files between the Ubuntu pc and your android phone via **wifi**.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the correct solution to your problem..

You can use Airdroid app on android market. It lets you access all you android folder in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to share media files, then `rygel` might be what you need. It's in the repositories. Type this command in a terminal to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install rygel rygel-preferences
```

Rygel is an uPnP DNLA service.

Answer (score 0):

"send anywhere" works with folders. it provide deb package and works well in ubuntu.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

You could give permission to a folder in two ways: (do them in ubuntu)

- Elevate your permission. Its always better to have superuser(sudo) permissions for your account if you own it. [How do I grant sudo privileges to an existing user?](https://askubuntu.com/a/168289/548850)
- Grand permission only to that file or folder. [How to change permission to folders and subfolders?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11512211/4676304). To do chmod you might need root user password.

Comment: The links will do...

Answer (score 0):

- In Nautilus, right-click on the folder that you want to share.
- Then select `Local Network Share`
- Check `'Allow others to create and delete files in this folder'`
- Check `'Guest access'`
- Apply
- Make sure both the computer and your android device is connected to the same network (wifi)

Most file manager apps in Android have the feature to search and connect to network drives (SMB) in the local network.

In new Samsung devices, you could use the 'Network Storage' feature provided in the default 'Files' app:

https://r2.community.samsung.com/t5/Tech-Talk/new-feature-Network-storage/td-p/4147865

Or use an app like ES File Explorer to connect to the shared storage.

Answer (score -1):

I save files on my Ubuntu machine.  Then I connect to it using sftp from within the ES File Explorer application for Android.  I made a bookmark to the Ubuntu directory on my Android desktop and can access it very conveniently.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to set up an SFTP server in Ubuntu. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.) They're not installed by default so -1 for this answer until you explain it or link to an explanation.