# How do I grant sudo privileges to an existing user?

Tags: sudo, privileges

I want to grant a newly created user `sudo` privileges in Ubuntu.

I tried

```
sudo adduser hduser admin
```

but it says no admin group exists.
How can I do it?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo visudo`?

Comment: This was changed recently, which is the reason for the confusion.

Comment: sudo adduser <username> sudo - did the trick for me. Second sudo is the group name instead of sudo

Answer (score 249, accepted):

You need to add the user `hduser` to the `sudo` group (which is the "administrators" group in Ubuntu).

If you have already created the user, you can add the user to the `sudo` group by running the following command in a Terminal:

```
sudo usermod -a -G sudo hduser
```

Comment: Note that the user must log off, then back on again for this change to take effect.

Comment: not working ubuntu 14

Comment: Usage: usermod [options] LOGIN

Options:
  -c, --comment COMMENT         new value of the GECOS field
  -d, --home HOME_DIR           new home directory for the user account
  -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE  set account expiration date to EXPIRE_DATE
  -f, --inactive INACTIVE       set password inactive after expiration
                                to INACTIVE
  -g, --gid GROUP               force use GROUP as new primary group
  -G, --groups GROUPS           new list of supplementary GROUPS
  -a, --append                  append the user to the supplemental GROUPS

Comment: No problem here using ubuntu 14.  Thx.

Comment: Yes , @JacobFoshee is right  - "user must log off, then back on again for this change to take effect."

Comment: still if i use visudo on the user i just added to sudo I will get permission denied, why is that ?

Comment: No problem here using ubuntu 16.

Comment: How do i remove sudo access from existing user ?

Comment: FYI, In RHEL/CentOS it is: sudo usermod -aG wheel hduser

Answer (score 28):

Instead you can try,

```
sudo adduser hduser sudo
```

In Ubuntu you need to add the user only to the group `sudo`.

Answer (score 16):

1) Become root. You can do this using `sudo -i` or becoming root the old fashioned way `su -`

2) Run `visudo`

3) I changed this portion of the sudoers file to have my chosen users become sudo users, and you can add users similarly (blank lines introduce to format cleanly):

```
## User Aliases
## These aren't often necessary, as you can use regular groups
## (ie, from files, LDAP, NIS, etc) in this file - just use %groupname
## rather than USERALIAS
# User_Alias ADMINS = jsmith, mikem dbadmin 
ALL=(ALL) ALL
ics ALL=(ALL) ALL 
csm ALL=(ALL) ALL 
coa ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

4) Press `:` and x to write the changes to sudoers and exit vi.

Comment: This seems needlessly complicated. Why bother running visudo when the [`adduser` command](http://askubuntu.com/a/7484/116961) will do what you want?

Comment: @dan-dascalescu - $ sudo adduser username sudo won't work if the 'sudo' group does not exist. So adding the user manually is certainly an option. However, it's certainly more elegant to create a sudo group, add it to the sudoers file (e.g. via visudo), then add the appropriate user(s) to that user group.

Comment: @JarrettBarnett That was the case for me. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Edit the sudoers file: `sudo visudo`

and add:

```
user    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Comment: Why bother editing `/etc/sudoers` when the [`adduser` command](http://askubuntu.com/a/7484/116961) will work?

Comment: @Zanna You have edited `sudo visudo /etc/sudoers` Is it correct? AFAIK, it is either `sudo visudo` or `sudo nano /etc/sudoers`

Comment: ah @Lnux you're right, but you should always use `visudo` to edit `/etc/sudoers` because it stops you from making a fatal syntax error. I corrected

Comment: @DanDascalescu maybe because for some people it doesnt work?