# How can I permanently grant root access to a user?

Tags: sudo, root

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I grant sudo privileges to an existing user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168280/how-do-i-grant-sudo-privileges-to-an-existing-user)

I've been searching for the answer to this but all I find is "It's not a good idea" or "We don't recommend it" and some work around solution is given...

I am a new, yes. There is a good chance I could break stuff, I know.  I am happy to break my OS and format it many times if it comes to that but restrictions of ANY kind on my OS enrage me.  I want to be able to break stuff if I want, then learn how I broke it and how to fix it.

I want the safety locks off.

Please tell me how to grant a user absolute authorisation.

Comment: Thanks :) and I won't.  I'll learn from my mistakes, the way it should be.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-run-as-root

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6676/why-is-there-no-option-to-login-as-root

Comment: Wrong approach, in your opinion. I'll do things my way. Thanks.

Comment: finally someone who stands up against these naysayers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone also wanting to liberate their system, this is the solution that worked for me:

1. load the Terminal
2. type: sudo passwd root
3. input your user's password when prompted
4. create UNIX password when prompted
5. type: sudo sh -c 'echo "greeter-show-manual-login=true" >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'
6. reboot the system
7. at the login screen there is now an option to login manually.  login with username 'root' and the password you created at step 4

Alternatively:

1. Throw your hard drive in the bin because it's been tainted by Ubuntu
   and you'll never be able to get that stink off it no matter how many
   times you format.
2. Install a new hard drive
3. Download a Puppy Linux distro from: http://puppylinux.com/

Comment: Will Chrome run at all when you do this?

Comment: No.  I had to keep the other user account open for normal usage

Comment: Then how is this answer any better than `sudo`?

Comment: Yep, you can enable the `root` account and use that, although that isn't a solution to the original problem. I didn't know that Chrome would refuse to run as `root`, but now I do. :)

Comment: @Bobson I didn't say it was better than Sudo. I said I wanted the safety locks off in order to learn, And hey would you look at that, I just learned that some programs will not operate when run as Root. Learning stuff already. No thanks to the stuck up Linux community and their obsession with everyone having to subscribe to the almighty Sudo methodology

Comment: @IchimitchHamono - I only vaguely even remember this question. I definitely don't remember what I was thinking when I wrote that comment five years ago. How did it work out for you? Did you learn anything from actually running as root?

Comment: Sorry @Bobson When you ask a technical 'how to' question and receive a lot of unhelpful opinions because people don't like what you're trying to do it becomes extremely frustrating and unfortunately I am sorely lacking in the patience department..  I was going back over this thread and my blood started boiling again...

Comment: Largely I've learned that being a Linux user still heavily relies on terminal usage over GUI.. to the point that the GUI often doesn't even behave the way it should due to user restrictions etc. Which in my opinion is not a good design philosophy. ie Linux is not for me. There is way to much unnecessary and counter-intuitive BS involved. I now use a rooted Android x86 distro with the #SuperUser module and occasionally I check in on Puppy Linux development out of interest.

Comment: @IchimitchHamono - I suspect that people saw this as an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/165591), where your question (Y) made no sense without also knowing what you really hoped to get out of it (X), and may not have been the best way to do so.  Kindof the equivalent to asking "How can I drive my car with the parking brake engaged?"  Honestly, I'm not sure why you thought that running as root would change Linux's reliance on the terminal, but I'm glad you learned what you set out to and found a choice that works better for you.

Comment: @Bobson Even if the question was "How can I drive my car with the parking brake engaged?" An answer would be along the lines of "Pull the lever in the center of the vehicle into the upward position and then apply pressure to the accelerator pedal" where as "That's dumb, don't do it" isn't an answer. It's an opinion. And one that really only serves to piss off the person who asked the question. They have their reasons to need to know how to do what they're asking how to do and speculation over their reasons or having the opinion that they shouldn't doesn't help anyone. It just muddies the water

Comment: @Bobson At the time I had hoped that not having to elevate privileges to complete trivial tasks would cut out having to type into a glorified dos prompt. It wasn't until later that I discover just how much of Linux use requires the use of the terminal. It sure is needlessly convoluted for a modern OS. Linux isn't at all superior to Windows the way the elitist community seems to think it is; but it could be. If they ever get off the 'design philosophy' high horse and start making user friendly distros. At the moment Puppy Linux is the closest thing to that.

Answer (score 49):

To give the user "foo" unlimited passwordless access to root privileges via the `sudo` command, edit `/etc/sudoers` and add the line:

```
foo   ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
```

See sudo(8) and sudoers(5) for more information.

As was suggested elsewhere, if you know how to use `vi` then it's a good idea to use `visudo` to edit `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: jdthood gave you an excelent tip. read this short article to find out more about the /etc/sudoers tricks :D. http://linuxg.net/understanding-etcsudoers-file/

Comment: Permission denied on Digital Ocean

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 28):

It is not *you* who is being restricted (as long as you can `sudo` or login as root on the command-line), but it is rather *every single application you run* that is being restricted.

If you give yourself root privileges, every application you run also gains complete power over your computer. *That* is the restriction, and saying you don't want any restrictions placed over you is like saying you do *not* want to lock your bike or your door, for it places a restriction upon yourself.

I am amazed no one as of yet has tried to offer you that insight.

Comment: This is *exactly* what I was trying to go for with my comment on another answer. The reason for the restriction by the Ubuntu devs is not because they think all users are inept; if that were the case, `sudo` would be disabled too. It's about giving the user the power to selectively give applications more privileges... and keeping the "bad ones" (be they buggy or malicious) from messing everything up à la Windows XP.

Comment: @IchimitchHamono You have root access? Sudo access? You have unrestricted access then. If that isn't what you EXPECT it to be, that's your lack of understanding and inability to learn. I bet money, that just like Android/iOS, you'll have to "Root" or "Jailbreak" before you'll get unfettered access on a Steam Box - Linux OR Windows. If typing "sudo", or learning how to edit /etc/sudoers, is too much restriction for you... You won't enjoy your future. Don't like it? Build your own OS - or find a Distro that doesn't have Sudo (or similar) installed.

Comment: @IchimitchHamono: by your own admission, you are new to this. That's completely fine. I even think your question is valid, and interesting. However, your sheer disinterest in finding out *why* it's not a good idea to actually *do* this, finding out *why* you only find posts saying "we don't recommend" it, astonishes me.

Comment: There's no need to be offended. I do understand what you're saying, and why you're saying it - security often gets in the way of user experience. All I'm saying is that you should understand the implications of your actions - essentially removing any and all restrictions imposed on each and every application or script you knowingly or unknowingly execute. If you do, and you're fine with running around in the woods, naked and covered in honey; without any means of defence, go ahead and enjoy. It's an interesting exercise.

Comment: Linux, and by extension, UNIX, was designed from the get-go as a multi-user operating system, fit for use in networks. Restricting user access is a logical implication of that design. As such, it is deeply embedded in the whole OS and applications that use it. Out of interest, what did you end up doing? Somehow allowing root to log in in a graphical environment?

Comment: Gaining root privileges is not very much like doing `chmod -R 777 /`. The latter gives *everyone* full powers over *files* which is quite different. Note that doing that `chmod` will certainly cause malfunctions.

Comment: fair point, removed that bit

Comment: Typical of the Linux community. You've not provided an answer. You've provided an unhelpful opinion. I am already aware of the Linux community's opinions on this topic and that I am an affront to your almighty deity 'Sudo'. I don't care. Your opinion is not needed, not wanted and definitely not helpful in answering my question.

Comment: -1, because this answer does not answer OPs question. If we do that on all other threads, why not here. I don't get that. Although the point is valid, it's OT.

Comment: does not answer the question

Answer (score 13):

Being a noob, you should better use `visudo` instead of editting `/etc/sudoers` on your own, at least because:

1. It checks that no one is using the `/etc/sudoers` file at the same
   time.
2. When you have finished, it checks the file for making sure it's fine.

Answer (score 13):

ok, this comes from my hacker days of trying everything in the system to see what it did.

There is a file `/etc/passwd` that famously holds passwords (or a marker to signify shadow passwords).

In that file, you will see something like this:

```
root:!:0:0::/:/usr/bin/ksh
daemon:!:1:1::/etc:
bin:!:2:2::/bin:
sys:!:3:3::/usr/sys: 
adm:!:4:4::/var/adm:
uucp:!:5:5::/usr/lib/uucp: 
guest:!:100:100::/home/guest:
nobody:!:4294967294:4294967294::/:
lpd:!:9:4294967294::/:
lp:*:11:11::/var/spool/lp:/bin/false 
invscout:*:200:1::/var/adm/invscout:/usr/bin/ksh
nuucp:*:6:5:uucp login user:/var/spool/uucppublic:/usr/sbin/uucp/uucico
paul:!:201:1::/home/paul:/usr/bin/ksh
jdoe:*:202:1:John Doe:/home/jdoe:/usr/bin/ksh
```

[example taken from [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.security/doc/security/passwords_etc_passwd_file.htm)]

the two sections that are interest to us are the numbers in position 3 and 4. the first one is the user ID, the second is the group. Notice that in this installation (and most installations) the values for root are both **0**

If you use *su* or *sudo* to edit this file, and change the numbers on your user ID to be the same as root, then you will become root. (also, you will not be able to use *rmuser* on your ID, as it is now considered essential to the system)

Comment: add another user and change that one to `:0:0:` - that way, you can choose to log in as root depending on which name you use on login

Comment: @IchimitchHamono: You have the power to 'fully access your system' with the default install. It's just that this power requires you to use the appropriate commands, namely `sudo` and the like, and enter your password when doing so. The existing setup, and the conventional wisdom of trying to keep things out of root, are there for very good reasons, one of which keeping buggy/malicious software from borking your system without your consent.

Comment: @Reid, +1 - the windows way of allowing access to everything is not a secure route, but getting used to the way *nix works is quite an adventure (I've still not made the change... too much game play)

Comment: if something requires root, and you are annoyed at having to type in that command again, `sudo !!` is your friend, and UAC is microsoft's attempt to be more *nix like - same as the prompt for passwords.

Comment: Changing the uid and gid of a user name to 0 and 0 is very likely to lead to problems down the road.

Comment: @jdthood Yup, I just did a sudo vi /etc/passwd and changed my uid to 0. After saving passwd, system doesn't know who I am and won't let me run any sudo commands. Yes, immediately creates problem.

Comment: @Sun "won't let me run any sudo commands." Not accepting sudo commands is not a problem is sudo commands are not necessary. The whole point in doing this is to avoid having to type sudo commands into a glorified dos prompt in order to complete mundane tasks,

Answer (score 10):

Wouldn't it be better to add the user to the correct group?

```
sudo usermod -a -G sudo hduser
```

see also this duplicate question: [How do I grant sudo privileges to an existing user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168280/how-do-i-grant-sudo-privileges-to-an-existing-user-in-12-04)

Comment: This allows hduser to sudo. hduser will of course have to enter a password when using sudo.

Comment: Nope. That absolutely would not be better.

Comment: If you do this, your user has the option to *become root*, using `sudo -i`. Then you have the user you want without restriction, without trying to get that same state for you normal user. Basically: if you want root powers, you should be root. And this gives you the way to do just that.