# account blocked by changing the /etc/passwd : how to revert or gain access again

Tags: 14.04, permissions, login, sudo, root

To get root access to my existing account in ubuntu i followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168280/how-do-i-grant-sudo-privileges-to-an-existing-user) post. But even after following the steps mentioned i wasn't able to create/modify file or directory without using the sudo keyword. 
Then i found one post which suggested that i can change the /etc/passwd and modify my username to match `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`. I followed, rebooted the system and then instead of my name in the welcome screen I saw the guest instead. While searching the net I found that root user is locked in ubuntu. Because i modified my username to match the root user, even my account is locked ( i think). 
How can i get it back? 
sudo is not working with guest account (as expected)

Comment: How exactly did you modify your username entry to "match" that of root? Have you actually tried rebooting into recovery mode and dropping to a root shell?

Comment: my bad, the statements were a bit ambiguous ....ofcourse i cannot modify my username to root, but matched the other parameters exactly similar to root. Here is how the user is listed in the /etc/passwd file 
`sanchit:x:0:0:Sanchit Jain,,,:/home/sanchit:/bin/bash`

it was `sanchit:x:1000:1000:Sanchit..` before i made the changes, i dont remember if i made any changes to last part of the line i.e. is to the `:/home/sanchit:/bin/bash` part

Comment: i haven't tried to reboot into recovery mode, as I am not aware of it. Will google it and try it.

Comment: @asteeldriver, AFAIK that requires you to set the root password before the incident, but I could be wrong. I added an alternate solution as an answer.

Comment: why is the question down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot your PC while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, you should see the GRUB menu appear. While focusing on the first Ubuntu entry, press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit it.

You should see a line which ends with `ro quiet splash --`. Change this last part to:

```
rw verbose init=/bin/bash --
```

Don't touch the first part of the string, leave it the same as before. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot. You should boot straight into a `root` shell. Now type:

```
sudo passwd sanchit
```

Choose a new password for your user. To recover the modified information, you should also do:

```
sudo nano /etc/passwd
```

Restore the correct user id and group for your user (they are both `1000` instead of `0`). Now type the following command to mount your filesystem back in read only mode:

```
sync
mount -o remount,ro /
```

Now switch off your PC using the power button. Turn the PC on again and it should work. If I can add a bottomline: next time, **think twice** before making these kind of changes to system files.

Comment: worked like a charm. Thank you! 
Will respect to the system files from now. _/\_

Comment: Can you please help me with my original problem too? I want to grant root privileges to the user. I tried to do it using `sudo usermod -a -G sudo sanchit` as told [here.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/168280/how-do-i-grant-sudo-privileges-to-an-existing-user) But even after this whenever i want to create a file or folder i have to prefix my commands with sudo.

Comment: Having `sudo` privileges does not mean you can do root operations without pre-pending it. It just means it will let you use `sudo` successfully.

Comment: Surprising.... i am using Sublime Text Editor. And i am not able to create new file using it, as sudo privileges are required. So i have create a file in terminal, provide read/write by chmod and then only i am able to work on the file, which is very cumbersome.

Comment: If you want to create a file as root, you must run the application by prepending `gksu ` in front of the command. Then you can save the file successfully.