# How do I backup my files from TTY login

Tags: backup, tty

I mistakenly changed permission recursively, issuing the following command on many files, including `/usr/bin/sudo`:

```
chown -R $USER:$USER sudo
```

Now I want to reinstall my Ubuntu OS but I need to back up my files on my external hard disk from the TTY. How do I do that step by step?

I currently do not have access to a Ubuntu installation medium and I don't want to loose my files.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I don't know what that is the only tool I have at my disposal is my external hard drive,

Comment: If you still have an Ubuntu USB or live DVD (the one you used for installation), you could use that to do this.

Comment: @JonasCz oh I don't have that

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto is that my only option because I don't have that on me and my major priority is backing up before reinstalling

Comment: Not the only one, but surely the easiest one. I will provide an answer with the "complicated" option, nevertheless. Still, you *need* an installation disk or USB drive for reinstalling Ubuntu. You should borrow a computer from a friend or in a library and burn the disk or the USB drive in any case. BTW: you gave details in the comments, please also append them to your question. Comments may be cleaned up any time.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto thank you for the tip, I would do that next time, I'm all ears on your solution

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto please just to be clear, you haven't actually spoken about me backing up do I have to use the disc or USB first before backing up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to back up my files on my external hard disk from the TTY.

You can't do it precisely from the TTY because you destroyed your `sudo` ability and probably you won't be able to mount the external drive. However, you have two options:

- booting in a root shell
- using a live DVD or USB

## Backup booting in a root shell

You cut yourself superuser powers, so you need to "hack" your own computer. As I explained in a [slightly related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/523220/271):

> Boot your PC while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, you
>   should see the GRUB menu appear. While focusing on the first Ubuntu
>   entry, press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit it.
>
> You should see a line which ends with `ro quiet splash --`. Change
>   this last part to:
>
> ```
> rw verbose init=/bin/bash --
> ```
>
> Don't touch the first part of the string, leave it the same as before.
>   Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot. You should boot
>   straight into a `root` shell.

Now you have root access and you can connect your external drive. After connecting it, wait a few seconds and do:

```
dmesg | tail
```

It will show a few lines where you can detect the device associated with the main partition of the external drive, probably `/dev/sdb1`. Create a mount point and mount the partition:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mkdir -p /mnt/external
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/external
```

Now prepare an output directory and copy the files:

```
mkdir /mnt/external/RECOVERED
cp -v -r /home /mnt/external/RECOVERED/
```

**Note:** if your home directory is in a separate partition you might need to mount it before doing the above. In that case `mount /home` should suffice.

When it's done, assure the data is written on the drive completely and unmount the file system:

```
sync
umount /mnt/external
```

Disconnect the external drive now. Since you plan to reinstall, I won't discuss how to clean up and shut down the computer safely. Just long-press the hardware power button. ;)

## Backup using a live DVD or USB

If you have access to a Ubuntu installation medium, do the following:

- boot your computer using the live DVD or USB
- connect the external hard drive
- run `sudo nautilus` in the terminal
- copy all the files you want in the external drive
- safely disconnect the drive
- re-install Ubuntu

Comment: I'm trying option one and it's telling me BOOTMGR is missing ?

Comment: Okay for the second option all I need to do is download ubuntu on a separate system load into an empty flash and use it as a live USB for booting ? , With the error message showing how do I use the USB for booting ?

Comment: @temiloluwaadesina «BOOTMGR is missing» then you are booting with another device inserted (probably a USB drive). You have to boot your hard drive as usual, just making sure that the GRUB menu shows up by pressing those keys.

Comment: →okay, I'm already downloading ubuntu Os and Rufus to make my USB stick live, so you're saying once I've done that I insert the USB stick and hard drive, use ctrl + shift and press e or do I insert the USB stick use the try ubuntu option and run the sudo nautilus cmd to transfer my files and then install Ubuntu ?

Comment: @temiloluwaadesina the choice is yours. I included both methods for completeness. Maybe the GUI approach is more user friendly, but honestly you can use both.

Comment: okay I'm using the GUI approach and I have two options try Ubuntu or install, I am on try ubuntu because I'm scared the other option would wipe all my data but I can't see all my files using try Ubuntu, do I install Ubuntu, does that give me the option to backup my data like Documents, Downloads and everything in my Home folder ?

Comment: @temiloluwaadesina «I can't see all my files using try Ubuntu» You need to click on the drive corresponding to the partition where your home directory is and browse it.