# How to recover formatted files?

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery

I was updating my laptop's software, the laptop hanged up so I shutted it down and restarted it after a while to find out that all the files were suddenly deleted, how can I recover the lost items?!

Comment: have you edited anything since?

Comment: How did you do the upgrade? By "all the files were suddenly deleted" you mean that after login you get a pristine desktop as if you installed Ubuntu brand-new? Please provide some more details in the Q.

Answer (score 1):

Try `scalpel`. [This](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/scalpel.1.html) is the manpage.

Or try GNU Parted.

Run:

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo parted /dev/sdx
```

Then run (in parted):

```
rescue START END
```

START and END are where the partition starts and ends.

Disclaimer: Please do not downvote my answer if it doesn't work as data recovery is one of the most various answerable questions and every method may or may not work.

Comment: Scalpel is a file carver. Are you sure the OP would like to get a bunch of randomly named files all in a single directory? :) IMHO it would be much better to do the customary attempts with `testdisk` and `extundelete` before that.

Answer (score 1):

When upgrading form one version of Ubuntu to another, some files and packages may be deleted in the process, as being considered no longer necessary after the update. That shouldn't happen to personal files though.

If you didn't secure erase those files, delete partitions or delete/replace the partition table, your files should still be recoverable. You can use LiveCD/USB with rescue tools, like Trinity Rescue Kit, Ultimate BootCD, Parted Magic.

Comment: While this might answer the question, I would suggest you add some guidance on the process. As it is, this A looks like a software recommendation more than a solution. Would you mind describing the process a bit more? Like e.g. the last part of this A: http://askubuntu.com/a/783575/271