# Does anyone have some suggestions for me I deleted some important files

Tags: data-recovery, rm

Is there a way to recover removed files in a situation such as described below? The command I executed was:

```
root@system:/# rm -r /tmp/letsencrypt.sh-XXXXXX l*
```

I tried to remove all the files in that directory that started with an `l`. When I noticed what I did it was too late, I know, pretty stupid...

I quickly made a snapshot after. Does anyone know some way to save my system? Or how I can search for files in it? It seems `ls` is also gone:

```
root@system:/# ls /tmp
bash: /bin/ls: No such file or directory
```

---

```
root@au-dev:/# echo *
bin boot dev etc home initrd.img media mnt opt proc root run sbin snap srv sys tmp usr var vmlinuz
```

Comment: Bad news: you need to reinstall your system. You have deleted every file in the system that starts with 'l', including all program libraries (typically starting with 'lib').

Comment: Use a live USB, choose "Try Ubuntu", and back up all your user data to a safe place. Then reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Follow Jos comment and re-install without formatting any of the partitions.  If it works you get your system back. Otherwise do a re-install with a restore of said backup

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `cd /; echo *`. I don't see why that command would have removed `ls`. It would have removed all your `/lib` directories, effectively breaking your system, but all of your data and files should be fine.

Comment: I thought that was interesting too, @terdon.  I can confirm, that command does remove `ls`, and the `l*` directories.

Comment: Well, I should add, it doesn't remove `ls` from /bin but it does make the command not work.

Comment: i am trying to start it with the ubuntu iso, normal start gives (as expected) a kernel error

Comment: Yeah, a livecd, should get you what you need.  I'm playing with a system where I deleted lib, and practically nothing works, but everything but `/l*` is untouched.

Comment: unfortunately, its on a really old pc, a bit slow, but it is great to hear that the files are rescuable, just got my lets encrypt script working for a ubiquity unifi controller

Comment: @bc2946088 oh, sure, it will break the command. It just won't remove it.

Comment: @oscrx: If my answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to recover removed files in a situation such as described below?

Technically, [yes](https://askubuntu.com/a/779197/271) for example using `testdisk`. However, it is not worth it. You basically deleted some system files (the entire `/lib` and `/lib64` directories) but **not your user data.**

Therefore, you are better off just making a copy of your home directory and reinstalling from scratch. I have described how to back up files using a live CD [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/783575/271), here's an excerpt:

> ## Backup using a live DVD or USB
>
> If you have access to a Ubuntu installation medium, do the following:
>
> - boot your computer using the live DVD or USB
> - connect the external hard drive
> - run `sudo nautilus` in the terminal
> - copy all the files you want in the external drive
> - safely disconnect the drive
> - re-install Ubuntu