# 16.04 upgrade failed, now I can't log in

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, data-recovery

The upgrade tool offered me to donwload ubuntu 16.04 (I was using 14.04). During the installation my computer freeze and and I had to boot it manually. Now I can´t log in. After I try to run the ubuntu option on GRUB I get a black screen with a few messages which end up with

-OK Started udev Kermel device manager
-Starting show plymouth boot screen...

I can be like that for hours, it wont load.

I tried runing the recovery mode, but my 14.04 login and pasword wont work anymore. What can I do? (I'm not computer smart) Is there a way I can re-install either 14.04 or 16.04 without loosing my files?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You can actually boot into a root shell from GRUB. Please [try this procedure](http://askubuntu.com/a/523220/271) and report if you can reach the root shell. If you can, then we can go on fixing your system.

Answer (score 3):

Try to boot from a Live USB stick and save your files in the cloud.

And, regarding your password, check on this question on AskUbuntu:

[How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)