# XUbuntu: Can't edit text files: Permission denied

Tags: xubuntu, mousepad

I am new to Linux, but I was under the impression that you can use GUI to edit text files I mean that is why GUI exists. I opened xrdp.ini and tried to edit it with Mousepad. When I try to save it I get `Failed to save document. Permission denied.`. I already used this method ([How do I grant sudo privileges to an existing user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168280/how-do-i-grant-sudo-privileges-to-an-existing-user)) to assign myself `sudo` permissions but I still can't edit this text file using GUI.

Comment: Do you start the text editor with root privileges ( using `sudo -s` or starting it with `sudo` at the beginning of the command )?

Comment: I start it using Whisker Menu or Applications Menu, that is through GUI.

Comment: Are you sure it's running with root permissions?

Comment: I am new to Ubuntu, so I really do not know.

Comment: I typed in terminal "gksudo mousepad" and it opened Mousepad in root. It works.

Comment: Well, it shows that mousepad isn't starting with root privileges when opening it from Whisker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to edit configuration files which require root privileges, you have to open application with root privileges. I opened Mousepad with root privileges by typing in terminal:

```
gksudo mousepad
```

Comment: gksudo is being removed from Ubuntu because Wayland has no close counterpart. For workarounds, see [pkexec recipe](https://askubuntu.com/a/1067364/232993) and [opening `admin:///etc/...' in apps using gvfs](https://askubuntu.com/a/999913/232993).