# I need an equivalent of gksu in 18.04

Tags: sudo, root, gksu

I've read a lot of threads about gksu being removed from many Linux flavours, including Ubuntu 18.04.  Many state that gksu is an abomination and no user should ever need to use anything like it.  I have 2 examples where, as far as I know, I must have something that allows me to run as root (not just for editing files).

First, I have a need to start mysql only after an encrypted folder is opened on (GUI) command.  This means having a script run by the encryption system that starts the mysql service.  That has to be done as root, so I use gksu in that startup script which asks me for a password.  How else can I start a service from a GUI system?

I also run Ubuntu system backups as root, otherwise many system files can't be backed up.  So the desktop file uses gksu to start the backup.

pkexec looks complicated, needing policy files.  Is that the only alternative, and if so, why is it any safer?

Other answers to similar questions don't seem to address individual issues that people have now that gksu is no more (or harder to find...).  I think such questions from non-expert users would benefit from more detailed answers.  I now have some, and so would like to answer my own question.

Comment: Does `pkexec` work for you instead of `gksu`?

Comment: @karel agreed, though that post doesn't *clearly* state the 'replacement' is `pkexec`.  (you have to hunt for it)

Comment: You can also try to use `sudo -H GUI-program` and if Wayland there is this link, that might be useful, [... there are workarounds, if you have a GUI tool, that works well for you and needs elevated permissions.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w/961978#961978)

Comment: This is a controversial topic but, in a nut shell, running graphical applications as root is a security risk. Although you, and many others, may not agree with this, running graphical apps as root is discouraged by Ubuntu and many distros. Ubuntu is in process of writing alternate solutions, pkexec and other policies. You can file a bug report and the developers will work on a solution to programs they feel should do so such as package managers. This is complex as it involves X and Wayland. Alternately use non graphical apps or write your own. Encryption does not require a gui

Comment: I use gnome-encfs-manager, which provides a gui to mount encrypted folders.  It provides for a script to be run when the drive is mounted.  In that script I need to start mysql.  How else can I do this?

As for wayland, not allowing synaptic or gparted guis is ridiculous from the point of view of an ordinary home desktop user.  They are invaluable.  Systems can be so secure that no one wants to use them - there's a balance, and in this particular case (wayland) the user must be right.

Comment: As for pkexec, I can't work out how to use it.  Sadly I'm a user, not a linux expert.

Comment: I am making some progress (but not using wayland).  It now seems gnome-encfs-manager will start mysql without gksu, and it still asks for my password.  I'm sure it used not to in earlier systems, but not matter., It does now.  

I also found http://www.webupd8.org/2015/03/how-to-run-gedit-and-nautilus-as-root.html which provides polkits for gedit and nautilus as root should I need them.

Comment: The remaining facility I use which needs root permissions is a full backup with deja-dup.  I can't get pkexec to work with it.  There already is a polkit for deja-dup duplicity, but I can't make sense of it. 
 It seems to be just about Restore, not Backup.   How do people do complete system backups with a gui tool without this?

Comment: Could you just go `sudo deja-dup --backup`? That starts the gui.

Comment: @ sudodus Wayland's depreciated and no longer the default in 18.04 LTS.

Comment: @K7AAY, I run Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Wayland in one computer. It is not the default, but it works for me. I would not say that it is deprecated. Maybe not mature yet ;-)

Answer (score 43):

I found this command

```
alias gksu='pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY'
```

in [this page](https://sites.google.com/site/installationubuntu/home/ubuntu-17-10/alternatives-for-gksu-and-gksudo)

After running the alias command:

```
gksu /path/to/script.sh
```

It will ask you for a password like normal.

You will need to add the alias to the end of `~/.bashrc` in order to keep the gksu command persistent on reboot.

Comment: Terrific, thank you so much. This practice of killing features without providing alternatives contributes to soo many hours of wasted time its not even funny. Thank you for fixing that, for me at least.

Comment: pkexec does not respect the sudoers - it only works if you give users access by putting them in the sudo group, not for permissions grated otherwise... (not sure if gksudo did respect that though)

Answer (score 10):

I know there are said to be answers to this elsewhere, but I have not found any of them clear and simple enough for me to resolve this issue.  So I dug around in many places and came up with this.  I still don’t understand why the Linux community has decided to make life so hard for us simple desktop users (and I have tried to understand many explanations), but that’s life.  I use the GUI for just about everything, only using the terminal window when necessary.  As far as I can tell solutions using sudo options don’t help with this.   So I have `.desktop` files and scripts that do all the jobs I use regularly.

There are two basic solutions.

#### 1. Reinstall `gksu`

This solution may or may not last.  Anti-gksu techies may find a way to stop it.  But in the mean time, download 2 `.deb` files from [libgksu (x64)](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libg/libgksu/libgksu2-0_2.0.13~pre1-9ubuntu2_amd64.deb) and [gksu (x64)](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gksu/gksu_2.0.2-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb).  Install libgksu2 and then gksu using gdebi or whichever installation tool you like to use.  This worked for me.

#### 2. Use `pkexec`

As a (hopefully) longer term solution, I managed to get pkexec to work for the tools I need.

1. To start a service from a script.  It turns out that neither gksu or pkexec is needed. Just `start service xyz` and it will ask for your password.
2. To edit root files, or to open nautilus as root, see [How To Run Gedit And Nautilus As Root With pkexec Instead Of gksu - Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/03/how-to-run-gedit-and-nautilus-as-root.html).  This provides two ‘polkit’ files for pkexec, that allow you to use a script containing `pkexec gedit` to edit a root file, and similarly for nautilus.  The instructions are all on that web page. I’m now using ‘filemanager-actions’ to provide right-click actions to run gedit or nautilus as root.
3. I run deja-dup as root for backups of the core system.  I do this infrequently, excluding `/home` (for `/home` I do frequent backups that don’t need root access).  To get this to work I took a copy of the file used in step 2 for gedit and edited it for deja-dup.  I don’t really understand the contents, but it does work, both for backups and to restore files, using `pkexec backup` in a script initiated from a .desktop file.  I added this new file to `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions` containing:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD polkit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN" "http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/policyconfig-1.dtd">

   <policyconfig>
     <icon_name>deja-dup</icon_name>

     <action id="org.gnome.DejaDup">
       <description gettext-domain="deja-dup">Backup</description>
       <message gettext-domain="deja-dup">Privileges are required to backup system files</message>
       <defaults>
       <allow_any>no</allow_any>
       <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
       <allow_active>auth_admin</allow_active>
        </defaults>
       <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/deja-dup</annotate>
       <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">true</annotate>
     </action>

   </policyconfig>
   ```

   Note that there is another deja-dup file in this directory, which claims to help with restoring files, but I couldn’t get it to work. This new file needs to have a unique name, such as `org.gnome.DejaDupNew.policy`.

I am, for now, running without gksu.  I’ll try to carry on…

Comment: The command to start the backup was `pkexec deja-dup` for me, after adding the file like you described. The dialog does let me choose the settings first, which is great.

Comment: Putting a policy file in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions` was indeed the way to create a desktop launcher with elevated `pkexec` permissions. Here is [another example](https://hamwaves.com/minivna.pro/en/index.html#launching-vnaj-withpkexec).

Answer (score 4):

Nautilus Admin (*nautilus-admin*) is a simple Python extension for the Nautilus file manager that adds some administrative actions to the right-click menu:

- Open as Administrator: opens a folder in a new Nautilus window     running with administrator (root) privileges.
- Edit as Administrator: opens a file in a Gedit window running     with administrator (root) privileges.

To install Nautilus Admin in all  currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install nautilus-admin
```

I've tested all the alternatives to gksu in 18.04 for other applications besides Files and Gedit, and the one that seems to work the most consistently is:

```
sudo -H appname &>/dev/null
```

`pkexec` is the best replacement for gksu when it works because it provides higher security, but it is very inconsistent across different apps (for example it doesn't work with Gedit) and can cause crashing with some apps. `sudo -i` is unnecessarily difficult to manage because it elevates your privileges to root for an extended period of time when you only need to be root to run a single command.

Answer (score 3):

I use a script called `sgedit` which inherits user preferences for font, tabs, and extensions. It uses `sudo -H gedit` instead of `gksu gedit` for stability in GUI environment. It prompts for a password.

### Have `sudo` inherit your user account `gedit` settings

[image: sgedit 80 column right slider.gif]

In this example the user settings for font name, font size, tab stops, convert tabs to spaces, 80 column highlight, and right side thumbnail slider bar have been inherited by `sudo`.

With regular `sudo -H gedit` you cannot make nor save these configuration settings. With the script below `sgedit` the settings are inherited from your user account.

This script also addresses the "`gksu` is bad and not installed by default" and "`pkexec` is hard to setup" problems.

---

### Background

I've been nagged by the same issue for years. This weekend's project was to write the `sgedit` script:

- Call using `sgedit filename1 filename2...`
- Gets user's gedit settings for tab stops, fonts, line-wrap, etc.
- Elevates to `sudo -H` to preserve file ownership whilst getting root powers.
- Requests password if last sudo has timed out.
- Gets sudo's gedit settings
- Compares differences between user and sudo gedit settings
- Runs `gsettings set` on the differences only (reduces 174 `set` commands to a dozen or less. Next time it's run perhaps only one or two changes but often times none.
- Calls gedit as a background task such that terminal prompt reappears immediately.

## Bash script `sgedit`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: sgedit
# PATH: /mnt/e/bin
# DESC: Run gedit as sudo using $USER preferences
# DATE: June 17, 2018.

# Must not prefix with sudo when calling script
if [[ $(id -u) == 0 ]]; then
    zenity --error --text "You cannot call this script using sudo. Aborting."
    exit 99
fi

# Get user preferences before elevating to sudo
gsettings list-recursively | grep -i gedit | grep -v history |
    grep -v docinfo |
    grep -v virtual-root | grep -v state.window > /tmp/gedit.gsettings

sudoFunc () {
    # Must be running as sudo
    if [[ $(id -u) != 0 ]]; then
        zenity --error --text "Sudo password authentication failed. Aborting."
        exit 99
    fi

    # Get sudo's gedit preferences
    gsettings list-recursively | grep -i gedit | grep -v history |
        grep -v docinfo |
        grep -v virtual-root | grep -v state.window > /tmp/gedit.gsettings.root
    diff /tmp/gedit.gsettings.root /tmp/gedit.gsettings | grep '>' > /tmp/gedit.gsettings.diff
    sed -i 's/>/gsettings set/g; s/uint32 //g' /tmp/gedit.gsettings.diff
    chmod +x /tmp/gedit.gsettings.diff
    bash -x /tmp/gedit.gsettings.diff  # Display override setting to terminal
    nohup gedit $@ &>/dev/null &
}

FUNC=$(declare -f sudoFunc)
sudo -H bash -c "$FUNC; sudoFunc $*;"
```

### Housekeeping

Copy the bash script above to a new file called `sgedit`. I recommend placing it in your `$HOME/bin` directory, i.e. `/home/YOURNAME/bin`. You may have to create the directory first.

Mark the file as executable using:

```
chmod a+x ~/sgedit
```

Note `~` is a shortcut for `/home/YOURNAME`.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04: Some installation programs and others do need gksudo or gksu to be available with the same name. To make these work:

Install gnome version of `ssh-askpass`. Without this the password dialog may be hidden behind another window:

```
sudo apt-get install ssh-askpass-gnome
```

Create new file `my-gksudo.sh`:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/profile.d/my-gksudo.sh
```

file content:

```
export SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/ssh-askpass
```

Create new files gksudo and gksu with identical content:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/bin/gksudo
```

and

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/bin/gksu
```

file content for both:

```
sudo -A $@
```

Make gksudo and gksu executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/gksudo
```

And

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/gksu
```

Reboot the computer.

Comment: Here's a slight variant on your answer: create a file that looks like this: `#!/bin/sh` \*\*  `export SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/ssh-askpass` \*\* `sudo "$@"`. (Replace the spaces and "\*\*" characters between  the hi-lighted sections with new lines.) Save that file somewhere like `/usr/local/bin/gksudo`. This will allow you to use this gksudo-substitute **only** when you want to. IDK what your solution will do in a non-graphical TTY, but I don't know if really want to find out the hard way. Also, with this solution, you don't need a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

XTerm is probably one's best choice.

```
xterm -e "sudo -b gedit /etc/fstab && sleep 1"
```

or

```
xterm -e su -c "gedit /etc/fstab &"
```

The latter assumes the root account is enabled and has a password set.

**-e** tells XTerm to open running a single command and **-c** tells su to run a single command as root.
In the first alternative, **-b** sends the application to the background after authenticating, which acts the same way in the second alternative, with **&**. This is required since XTerm would remain open if the application is in the foreground.
The **sleep 1** command is required because, for a unknown reason, the application would fail to run.

If the first alternative fails, use the following.

```
xterm -e sudo su -c "gedit /etc/fstab &"
```

Here's an alias which resembles gksu.

```
gksu(){
  xterm -e "sudo -b $* && sleep 1"
}
```

Paste it to **.bashrc**. Make sure to relog before using it.

One could also place it in a binary directory so the command becomes system-wide.

```
cd /usr/local/bin && sudo su -c "echo 'xterm -e \"sudo -b \$* && sleep 1\"' > gksu && chmod 0755 gksu && ln -s gksu gksudo" && cd ~
```

Answer (score 1):

**WHAT ABOUT INSTALLING THE (DEPRECATED) GKSU BACK?**

For anyone wondering if it's still possible to install `gksu`, the answer is *possibly **yes***: even though its DEB packages are deprecated since ~2015, by December 9, 2020, they were still available for download at Launchpad. The following solution worked on the 64-bit (AKA *amd64*) XUbuntu versions 18.04 (upgraded from 16.04) and 20.04 (fresh install) that I'm currently using.

---

**IN A NUTSHELL**

What I did was to download these 7 DEB packages:

- [multiarch-support_2.17-93ubuntu4_amd64.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/153554150/multiarch-support_2.17-93ubuntu4_amd64.deb)
- [libgcrypt11_1.5.0-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/147472576/libgcrypt11_1.5.0-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb)
- [libgnome-keyring-common_3.8.0-2_all.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/141785150/libgnome-keyring-common_3.8.0-2_all.deb)
- [libgnome-keyring0_3.8.0-2_amd64.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/141785305/libgnome-keyring0_3.8.0-2_amd64.deb)
- [libgtop2-10_2.30.0.is.2.30.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/182650077/libgtop2-10_2.30.0.is.2.30.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb)
- [libgksu2-0_2.0.13_pre1-6ubuntu7_amd64.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/182741643/libgksu2-0_2.0.13%7Epre1-6ubuntu7_amd64.deb)
- [gksu_2.0.2-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/193391454/gksu_2.0.2-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb)

...and then install them with the help of `gdebi`: a DEB package manager that not only installs DEB packages but also checks and solves (i.e. installs) their dependencies. It is mandatory to install the *multiarch-support* package first, then install the *libgcrypt11* package, and so on (following that strict order from the top till the bottom of the list) until you end up installing the last package (i.e. the *gksu* one).

---

**INSTALLATION EXPLAINED (GRAPHICAL METHOD)**

1. For each one of the 7 links from the list above, right click the link, then select **Save link as...** and then save the DEB package in your `Downloads` folder (e.g. `/home/yourname/Downloads`).
2. Start `gdebi` in graphical mode (i.e. `gdebi`'s frontend). If you can't find `gdebi` in your *Applications* menu (it's usually located in *System*), open a terminal emulator window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> usually does the trick), then type `sudo gdebi-gtk &` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, type your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.
3. At the `gdebi` window, click on **File**, then click on **Open...**, then open your `Downloads` folder, select the first package to be installed (i.e. *multiarch-support_2.17-93ubuntu4_amd64.deb*), click on **Open** and then click on **Install Package**. Repeat these steps for the other packages (don't forget to follow the strict order of the list above, from top to bottom). The last package to be installed will therefore be *gksu_2.0.2-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb*.

As soon as you're done performing these 3 simple steps, `gksu` will be available at your *Applications* menu.

---

**INSTALLATION EXPLAINED (TERMINAL / TEXT-MODE METHOD)**

1. Start a terminal emulator window so you have access to the Linux shell ("command prompt"). Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> will likely do the trick.
2. Type `mkdir ~/gksu` in the emulator window and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will create a `gksu` folder in your home folder (e.g. `/home/yourname/gksu`).
3. Type `cd ~/gksu` in the emulator window and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will cause `~/gksu` (i.e. the `gksu` folder in your home folder) to become your working directory (i.e. the folder where your current shell session is active, i.e. the folder to which your user account is currently connected through the Linux shell emulator window).
4. Select and then copy the command below:

   ```
   wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/153554150/multiarch-support_2.17-93ubuntu4_amd64.deb ; wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/147472576/libgcrypt11_1.5.0-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb ; wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/141785150/libgnome-keyring-common_3.8.0-2_all.deb ; wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/141785305/libgnome-keyring0_3.8.0-2_amd64.deb ; wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/182650077/libgtop2-10_2.30.0.is.2.30.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ; wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/182741643/libgksu2-0_2.0.13~pre1-6ubuntu7_amd64.deb ; wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/193391454/gksu_2.0.2-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   ```
5. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste the above command in the emulator window and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The `wget` program will then download all these 7 required DEB packages and place them all in `~/gksu`.
6. Once the download is finished, select and then copy this other command:

   ```
   sudo gdebi -n multiarch-support_2.17-93ubuntu4_amd64.deb ; sudo gdebi -n libgcrypt11_1.5.0-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb ; sudo gdebi -n libgnome-keyring-common_3.8.0-2_all.deb ; sudo gdebi -n libgnome-keyring0_3.8.0-2_amd64.deb ; sudo gdebi -n libgtop2-10_2.30.0.is.2.30.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ; sudo gdebi -n libgksu2-0_2.0.13~pre1-6ubuntu7_amd64.deb ; sudo gdebi -n gksu_2.0.2-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   ```
7. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste the above command in the emulator window and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then type your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again. For every instance of the `gdebi` command, it will install the corresponding DEB package. The `-n` parameter tells `gdebi` to automatically solve package dependencies, thus `gdebi` won't ask you questions: instead, it will automatically install the main package and will also automatically detect, download and install its occasional DEB package dependencies.

As soon as you're done performing these 7 steps, `gksu` will be available at your *Applications* menu.

Answer (score 0):

Just a marginal addition for those who want to use a gksu supplement in a **desktop** file to run a WINE program as admin. In my case **Total Commander** was the target program (I apologize to those from whom this provokes resistance). I wanted to run it as admin from the **Unity Launcher**.

Here is my solution:

```
Exec=sh -c "zenity --password --title=\"sudo password prompt\" --timeout=10 2>/d
ev/null | sudo -S -H wine \"/root/.wine/drive_c/totalcmd/TOTALCMD.EXE\""
```

This will prompt you for the password, and then pass it to sudo.

Here is the whole content of the desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=/home/zsolti/MyApps/.icons/Total_commander_Admin64.png
Name[en_US]=TotalCommanderAdmin
Exec=sh -c "zenity --password --title=\"sudo password prompt\" --timeout=10 2>/d
ev/null | sudo -S -H wine \"/root/.wine/drive_c/totalcmd/TOTALCMD.EXE\""
Comment[en_US]=Total Commander Admin
Name=TotalCommanderAdmin
Comment=Total Commander Admin
Icon=/home/zsolti/MyApps/.icons/Total_commander_Admin64.png
```