# Cannot open and update /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf

Tags: 18.04, sudo, root, synaptics, gksu

I am new to Linux and have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04. I need to edit the `50-synaptics.conf` file in Ubuntu 18.04, but GKSU is deprecated, and when I run

```
gedit admin:///usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

it shows:

```
The specified location is not mounted.
```

What should I do to open and update this file?

**output**

```
aayush@aayush-taneja:~$ gksu gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf  
Command 'gksu' not found, did you mean:

  command 'ksu' from deb heimdal-clients
  command 'ksu' from deb krb5-user
  command 'gosu' from deb gosu

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

aayush@aayush-taneja:~$ sudo apt install gksu
[sudo] password for aayush: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gksu is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gksu' has no installation candidate

aayush@aayush-taneja:~$ gedit admin:///usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf

** (gedit:4614): WARNING **: 22:17:30.045: The specified location is not mounted
^C
```

Comment: How about `sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`?

Comment: Didn't work. The document it opened was empty. @mikewhatever

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need an equivalent of gksu in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042344/i-need-an-equivalent-of-gksu-in-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

1. First go to filesystem.
2. Then `usr`.
3. Then `share`.
4. Then `x11`.
5. There you will see a file named as `51-synaptics-quirks.conf`

   You cannot edit the file so you have to open that directory as root.

   Just right click in the directory and select "open as root."

   Then open up the file and paste it at the end after the END SECTION:

   ```
   # Disable generic Synaptics device, as we're using
   # "DLL0704:01 06CB:76AE Touchpad"
   # Having multiple touchpad devices running confuses syndaemon
   Section "InputClass"
       Identifier "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
       MatchProduct "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
       MatchIsTouchpad "on"
       MatchOS "Linux"
       MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
       Option "Ignore" "on"
   EndSection
   ```

Comment: AFAIK the "open as root" option is not provided anymore, the aforementioned Ubuntu release (18.04) doesn't even have `gksu` in the repos in the first place.

Comment: i have installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS there is opption of  "open as a root" .

Comment: gedit admin:///usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
  

-->donot do this just go there manually and change the contents of file.

Comment: You probably installed something for the "open as root" option, e.g. `nautilus-admin`. It should not be available *by default*.