# Current status of ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, administrator, gksu

I have not yet migrated to Ubuntu 18.04, due to the great changes made to the system. These are the withdrawal of gksu, the use of gnome-desktop, among others.

When I tried I had terrible problems on account of gksu, so my questions are:

- How is the situation of Ubuntu 18.04?
- Have you been able to meet the need for gksu?
- Is the software compatible with a new administrative method?
- Otherwise, do you still have some way to reinstall it in the system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need an equivalent of gksu in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042344/i-need-an-equivalent-of-gksu-in-18-04)

Answer (score 1):

> - How is the situation of Ubuntu 18.04?

I'm running Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and it works well for me. I have a test system of standard Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS too, and I think it works well.

**'Don't fix it if it ain't broke.'**

My general recommendation is to stay with a working version as long as it is supported or at least until the next first point release of the next LTS version (16.04.1 LTS, 18.04.1 LTS, 20.04.1 LTS). Switch to a new version before the old version passes end of life (LTS: 5 years for standard Ubuntu and 3 years for the community flavours.)

> - Have you been able to meet the need for gksu?

Yes, there are alternatives to `gksu`. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w/961978#961978).

In Xorg it is enough with

```
sudo -H gui-program
```

In Wayland you also need

```
xhost +si:localuser:root
```

to allow it to work.

> - Is the software compatible with a new administrative method?

I don't understand what you mean.

> - Otherwise, do you still have some way to reinstall it in the system?

Reinstalling Ubuntu is done as in previous versions. Or do you mean `gksu`? Don't try to use it in 18.04 LTS.