# GKSu Installation error

Tags: gksu

```
sudo apt install gksu -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gksu is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gksu' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? `gksu` has been removed from the past few Ubuntu releases.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using Ubuntu 18.04 and above.

The `gksu` program is [deprecated](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/umit/+bug/1740618) for Ubuntu 18.04 and later versions.
An alternative is [`pkexec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pkexec.1.html), which comes preinstalled with Ubuntu 18.04+.

You can find some more options in [Pekka Lehtikoski's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1167911/618353) in [I need an equivalent of gksu in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1042344/618353).

Comment: thanks all for help me